# Obtain list of GCE projects with Apache libcloud

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, libcloud

The method [projects.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) provides details on the API call to request Google Computer Engine "projects". Is it possible to do this also with [libcloud](https://libcloud.apache.org/)? I haven't found any reference in the documentation nor the source code, so I think it's not possible straight away.

If that's the case, could anyone provide some help on how this could be implemented? Initializing `GCENodeDriver` is not an option because it requires a project to be provided. However, when initializing it with a proper project, I could use the `connection` reference it contains. But so far, my attempts to issue a

```
response = conn.request('https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects', method='GET')
```

didn't result in anything useful

> (`libcloud.common.google.ResourceNotFoundError: u'Not Found'`).

I wonder if I can use the same authentication for this call (using service account and authentication json file). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [**projects.list**](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) it only talks about the successful response case.

> **Method: projects.list**
>
> Lists Projects that are visible to the user and satisfy the specified
>   filter. This method returns Projects in an unspecified order. New
>   Projects do not necessarily appear at the end of the list.
>
> HTTP request
>
> ```
> GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects
> ```
>
> The URL uses Google API HTTP annotation syntax.
>
> **Request body**
>
> The request body must be empty.
>
> **Response body**
>
> If successful, the response body contains data with the following
>   structure:
>
> A page of the response received from the projects.list method.
>
> A paginated response where more pages are available has nextPageToken
>   set. This token can be used in a subsequent request to retrieve the
>   next request page.

I'm not too familiar with `libcloud`, so do not know what `Not Found` means. To me it looks like the request got a 404 response.

I can make the following recommendations to confirm that the service account you're using has the required permissions and authentication scopes.

- I'm not exactly sure which permissions/roles the service account needs to have, but I feel it should have permissions at the organization level to be able to list projects. I could not find any info about this in the documentation.
- Here is the info about authorization scopes required to call this API.

> [**Authorization**](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list#authorization)
>
> Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:
>
> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The `projects.list` endpoint uses a different hostname and different OAUTH scope for permissions, and doesn't fit well into the flow of apache libcloud. I ended up adding some extra `googleapiclient` code to my libcloud script to fetch the project list:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

projects = {}
kf = 'projectname-12345.json'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(kf)
projapi = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1',
                          credentials=creds).projects()
req = projapi.list()
while req:
    resp = req.execute()
    for project in resp.get('projects',[]):
        projects[project['projectId']] = project
    req = projapi.list_next(previous_request=req,
                            previous_response=resp)

print(sorted(projects))
```